# Ad failed to load : 3 when trying Admob sample app

Tags: android, admob

I've downloaded and installed the kotlin adbmob banner sample found here:
https://github.com/googleads/googleads-mobile-android-examples/tree/master/kotlin/admob/BannerExample

After that, the only thing I did was replacing the testDeviceId with my own test device id (as shown in LogCat)

```
  MobileAds.setRequestConfiguration(
      RequestConfiguration.Builder()
        .setTestDeviceIds(listOf("B5A00D93D9B06ED1EF1871EA3C2ABD1C"))
        .build()
    )
```

The banner never gets shown and logcat is showing : "Ad failed to load : 3"

So why am I not receiving test ads?

I tried googeling this but it doesn't provide me with clear answers.

Comment: what error do you get if you use a fake testDeviceId?

Comment: same error nothing changes, i did just found out that everything works fine on an emulator though

Comment: that strongly indicates that your testDeviceId is invalid

Comment: I'm only copying the id from logcat, i don't see how it can be wrong. I also tried adding the device as a test device from the admob ui but that doesn't have any effect either

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resetted my advertising id in settings -> google and somehow it works now.

Really disappointing how bad the Admob documentation is regarding testing